# Solving for X when given the sum of an infinite geometric series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I go about finding a variable in the summation equation if I am given the answer to the summation as so: $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 7(x)^{n-1} =25$

I know that x has to be less than 1 because anything above 1 will simply diverge. I know that the first term in the series will always be 1 when n = 1. However I cannot seem to figure out how to narrow it down any further. How would I solve for x here?

Comment: I don't understand the formula. Try to use $ to enter math mode (one dollar at the beginning and another in the end). Also use \lim instead of \limits

Comment: I tried to make the formula readable. Is this correct ?

Comment: Sorry I was still trying to figure out mathjax, this is the correct formula now.

Comment: Use the formula for the geometric series: If $q \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\vert q \vert < 1$, it is $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty q^k = \frac{1}{1-q}$.

Comment: Hint: $\frac1{1-x}=\frac{25}7$.

Comment: Thank you both so much! Would you be able to show me how you got to that equation Yves?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 1):

Okay so based off of the hints I've got, I think I figured out how to answer this now. Hopefully this will help others who might see this in the future.

So I start with $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 7(x)^{n-1} =25$

I pull the 7 to the front and get $7\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (x)^{n-1} =25$

I divide both sides by 7 to get rid of it and get $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (x)^{n-1} =\frac{25}{7}$

Using the formula for geometric series I can substitute $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (x)^{n-1}$ for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ leaving me with

$\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{25}{7}$

Solving for that gives me x = $\frac{18}{25}$ which was the correct answer.

Thanks to everyone for the help! If I got anything wrong please feel free to correct any of my errors.